# Any way to select top n PCA components from accumulative PCA plot in R?

Tags: r, pca, feature-selection

I am interested to pick up top 10 PCA components from accumulative PCA plot for my dataset. I managed to get PCA plot such as scree plot, pairs plot and so on, but it doesn't make much sense to me. So I want to select top 10 PCA plot from its accumulative PCA plot and I did it, but I need to subset my original dataset by using this top 10 PCA component. Can anyone point me out to how to make attempt more accurate and desirable?

**reproducible data**:

```
persons_df <- data.frame(person1=sample(1:200,20, replace = FALSE),
                    person2=as.factor(sample(20)),
                    person3=sample(1:250,20, replace = FALSE),
                    person4=sample(1:300,20, replace = FALSE),
                    person5=as.factor(sample(20)),
                    person6=as.factor(sample(20)))

row.names(persons_df) <-letters[1:20]
```

**my attempt**:

```
my_pca <- prcomp(t(persons_df), center=TRUE, scale=FALSE)
summary(my_pca)

my_pca_proportionvariances <- cumsum(((my_pca$sdev^2) / (sum(my_pca$sdev^2)))*100)
```

**public dataset**:

since I have some issue when I created above reproducible data, here I linked [public example dataset](http://[](https://jmp.sh/v/3b95GawudPvW6edMGzhA))

here I need to select top 10 PCA component for `persons_df`, then subset original data then run a simple linear regression on that. How can I make my approach complete here in order to achieve my goal? Can anyone quickly point me out here? any idea?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195836/discussion-on-question-by-dan-any-way-to-select-top-n-pca-components-from-accumu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use PCA for dimensionality reduction, in brief:

1. Omit your output variable (that's cheating) and create contrast variables with `model.matrix` if necessary. (Don't directly one-hot encode factors with lots of levels like zip code, or the size of your data will explode. Think smarter.) Remove any zero-variance variables. Deal with `NA`s.
2. Scale. A variable with a large scale (like salary) can make everything else look low-variance by comparison.
3. Run PCA with `princomp` or `prcomp`.

```r
pca <- princomp(scale(cbind(mtcars[-1])))
```

4. To get the percentage of variance explained, pull the `stdev` vector out of the PCA object, square it to get variance, and scale by the sum so it sums to 1.

```r
pct_var_explained <- pca$sdev^2 / sum(pca$sdev^2)
pct_var_explained
#>      Comp.1      Comp.2      Comp.3      Comp.4      Comp.5      Comp.6 
#> 0.576021744 0.264964319 0.059721486 0.026950667 0.022225006 0.021011744 
#>      Comp.7      Comp.8      Comp.9     Comp.10 
#> 0.013292009 0.008068158 0.005365235 0.002379633
```

5. Look at the cumulative sum of variance explained to see how many principal components you want to retain. For example, components 9 and 10 explain less that 0.25% of variance here. You can also use `summary` to do these calculations for you.

```r
cumsum(pct_var_explained)
#>    Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3    Comp.4    Comp.5    Comp.6    Comp.7 
#> 0.5760217 0.8409861 0.9007075 0.9276582 0.9498832 0.9708950 0.9841870 
#>    Comp.8    Comp.9   Comp.10 
#> 0.9922551 0.9976204 1.0000000

summary(pca)
#> Importance of components:
#>                           Comp.1    Comp.2     Comp.3     Comp.4
#> Standard deviation     2.3622469 1.6021366 0.76062599 0.51096437
#> Proportion of Variance 0.5760217 0.2649643 0.05972149 0.02695067
#> Cumulative Proportion  0.5760217 0.8409861 0.90070755 0.92765822
#>                            Comp.5     Comp.6     Comp.7      Comp.8
#> Standard deviation     0.46400943 0.45116656 0.35884027 0.279571602
#> Proportion of Variance 0.02222501 0.02101174 0.01329201 0.008068158
#> Cumulative Proportion  0.94988322 0.97089497 0.98418697 0.992255132
#>                             Comp.9     Comp.10
#> Standard deviation     0.227981824 0.151831138
#> Proportion of Variance 0.005365235 0.002379633
#> Cumulative Proportion  0.997620367 1.000000000
```

6. Subset to the principal components you want to keep and cbind your output variable back on.

```r
train <- data.frame(
    mpg = mtcars$mpg, 
    predict(pca)[, cumsum(pct_var_explained) < 0.95]
)
```

7. Train your model.

```r
model <- lm(mpg ~ ., train)
summary(model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = train)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -4.2581 -1.2933 -0.4999  1.3939  5.2861 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 20.09062    0.44345  45.305  < 2e-16 ***
#> Comp.1      -2.28131    0.18772 -12.153 3.17e-12 ***
#> Comp.2       0.11632    0.27679   0.420   0.6778    
#> Comp.3       1.29925    0.58301   2.229   0.0347 *  
#> Comp.4      -0.09002    0.86787  -0.104   0.9182    
#> Comp.5       0.31279    0.95569   0.327   0.7461    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 2.509 on 26 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.8547, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8268 
#> F-statistic: 30.59 on 5 and 26 DF,  p-value: 4.186e-10
```

This particular model pretty much just needs 1 principal component—there's a lot of information the model can't do anything with in there. (Maybe it's irrelevant, redundant, or nonlinear.) Iterate.